# do i need an I/O shield for quadcopter motors

Tags: arduino-mega

I would like to know if I need an I/O shield for the 4 ESC's on a Quadcopter I am building using Arduino Mega2560.  The current to the ESC's should come from the battery itself and the data from the board so my first thought is that it is not needed however I wanted to be sure.

Comment: What's an I/O shield?

Comment: You really do not want to be flying a literal Arduino, especially not a mega - it just means excess weight, bulky awkward connectors, and unsuitable power circuitry.  Even the projects that were once Arduino *derived* have typically moved on, first to purpose-designed ATmega boards and now to ARM boards.

Answer (score 1):

If the ESC accepts a signal that the Arduino can generate (i.e., 5V PWM) then no interfacing is required.

If the ESC is running from 3.7V (or similar) then some level shifting may be required to reduce the 5V signal to 3.7V, depending on the ESC. That may be built on a shield of some form or just with discrete resistors wired in manually to the leads.